# Priority Queue and Set in Java or general

Tags: data-structures, queue

why do we need priority queue when a set always keeps its object sorted, I think we can always remove the first/last element of a set and it would work as priority queue because priority queue offers the element with max priority(last or first positioned element in sorted collection),  apart from the fact that set does not allow duplicate is there a major difference or am I completely on a wrong track of thoughts?

Comment: Priority queues have a specific purpose, and it is not a simple FIFO queue. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue  .  Sets are a collection of unique values, and are used for different purposes.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(abstract_data_type)

Comment: So yes, you are thinking about the problem incorrectly.  You may not need a priority queue if you aren't dealing with a queue of work.

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly have an *implementation* of a set having priority behavior that conforms to some *interface* for a set.  Nothing prevent you from doing that, other than possibly confusing those folks that expect a certain kind of behavior from a *set* that your priority implementation doesn't fulfill.

We generally call such a mechanism a "priority queue" (and treat it as such) because that is more descriptive of the actual behavior we are providing.

Answer (score 1):

When you are dealing with a problem that wants to repeatedly consume "the first" thing of a collection of things, you use a type that satisfies the interface `PriorityQueue`.

When you are dealing with a problem that wants an ordered, unique collection of things, you use a type that satisfies the interface `SortedSet`.

That the *implementation* of one uses the *implementation* of the other (or not) doesn't (and shouldn't) matter.

Comment: Sets are typically unordered, only lists are always ordered.

Comment: @mljrg I was thinking `TreeSet`, which is a `Set`, and maintains things in `comparator()` order

Comment: @Caleth - whereas a PriorityQueue doesn't maintain items in an order maintained by a comparator: it also resolves items that compare equal by keeping them in order of inserrion, while a TreeSet would not allow a new item to be added if an existing item compared as equal.

Answer (score 0):

The PriorityQueue provides the largest or smallest element in O(1) time, which is not possible by TreeSet. Since TreeSet is backed by a red-black tree, the search operation will take O(logN) time.

This is why if you are developing an application where priority matters e.g. a job scheduling algorithm where you always want to execute the job with the highest priority, you should use a PriorityQueue data structure.

Read more [here](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2017/04/difference-between-priorityqueue-and-treeset-in-java.html#ixzz6ZuJIPAr3).